# Estimate on first derivatives given $L^2$-norm of Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

Let $B$ be the unit ball in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the set of functions
$$X=\{u\in C^2(\bar B) \mid u|_{\partial B}=0 \text{ and } \|\Delta u\|_{L^2(B)}\leq 1\},$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian.

> Is it true that the set of first derivatives $\{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}|\, u\in X\}$ is pre-compact in $L^2(B)$?

Comment: Yes, it is true. You will find this in any textbook on elliptic PDEs.

Comment: Do you have a more precise reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true and the "proof" is as follows (I wouldn't really dare to call that a proof, though).
For any $u\in X$ write $f=-\Delta u$, and observe that trivially $u$ solves the elliptic PDE
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-\Delta u=f & \mbox{in }B\\
u=0 & \mbox{on }\partial B
\end{array}
\right..
$$
(This is a tautology, if you will.)
By standard elliptic regularity (see e.g. Evans' textbook on PDEs, section 6.3.2 and in particular remark (i) just after theorem 4) we get that
$$
\|u\|_{H^2(B)}\leq C \|f\|_{L^2(B)}=C \|\Delta u\|_{L^2(B)}\leq C
$$
for some purely dimensional $C\equiv C(n)$.
In other words, your set $X$ is bounded in $H^2$. The precompactness then follows from the [Rellich-Kondrachov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem) applied to $u_i=\partial_{x_i}u$, with of course $\|\nabla u_i\|_{L^2}\leq \|u\|_{H^2}$ (the full Hessian of $u$ controls any first derivative of $u_i$).

For a more "serious" reference (by that I mean not a textbook) I can recommend Gilbarg-Trudinger.